# How can I store two smallint values in a varbinary(max)?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am dealing with a SQL table that has a column of type varbinary(max). I intend to store two Int16 values in it via a stored procedure. I am going to consume this column value in C# code so I was hoping if I could do something like 'save one value in the first 8 bits and second value in last 8 bits', etc. I explored SQL bitwise operators but was unable to conclude how I can do it.

Would greatly appreciate if I can get any pointers or links to read-up.

Comment: Why can't you use two columns?

Comment: Adding a column just for this is not an option.

Comment: Please take note that while you *can* do that, you are going to violate one of the most basic design principles of relational DBs, namely [First Normal Form (1NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form): each column should contain only atomic (i.e. non-composite) values. You'd be well-advised to simply extend your table with two `smallint` columns.

Comment: @Aniruddha.. what is the use of this varbinary column? To store variables of type small*? Stakx has a very valid point here.

Comment: I agree, in my case though, put simply, the table stores state of a generic type. Type specific handlers then consume records from it. The column is question is where type specific info could be saved, in whatever format one wants, that will be consumed by that specific type handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the stored procedure parameters to binary and concatenate them:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (BinaryValue VARBINARY(MAX)) 

DECLARE @Int1 SMALLINT
DECLARE @Int2 SMALLINT 

SELECT 
    @Int1 = 32767,  
    @Int2 = -32768

INSERT @T (BinaryValue) 
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(@Int1,0) AS VARBINARY(2)) + CAST(ISNULL(@Int2,0) AS VARBINARY(2))

SELECT 
    BinaryValue, 
    Int1 = CAST(SUBSTRING(BinaryValue, 1, 2) AS SMALLINT) ,
    Int2 = CAST(SUBSTRING(BinaryValue, 3, 2) AS SMALLINT) 
FROM 
    @T
```

Comment: Good solution. Just one thing: Depending on the DB settings, if either `@Int1` or `@Int2` are `NULL`, this solution might not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To store 2 `Int16` values, you obviously need a total of 32 bits, or 4 bytes.  Here is some C# code that shows you how you can convert your 2 `Int16` values to a byte array and back the other way around using bit shifting.

I realize that you may need to do some of this inside a stored procedure.  But if you study the simple bit shifting logic, you shouldn't have a hard time translating the logic into your procedure.

Hopefully this will get you started:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int16 value1 = 12345;
    Int16 value2 = 31210;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    bytes[0] = (byte)(value1 >> 8);
    bytes[1] = (byte)value1;
    bytes[2] = (byte)(value2 >> 8);
    bytes[3] = (byte)value2;

    // store the byte array in your db column.

    // Now let's pretend we're reading the byte array and converting back to our numbers.
    Int16 decodedValue1 = (Int16)((bytes[0] << 8) | bytes[1]);
    Int16 decodedValue2 = (Int16)((bytes[2] << 8) | bytes[3]);
    Console.WriteLine(decodedValue1); // prints 12345
    Console.WriteLine(decodedValue2); // prints 31210
}
```

Here is another way to do it without explicit bit shifting in C#, by using the built-in `BitConverter` class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int16 value1 = 12345;
    Int16 value2 = 31210;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value1), 0, bytes, 0, 2);
    Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value2), 0, bytes, 2, 2);

    // store the byte array in your db column.

    // Now let's pretend we're reading the byte array and converting back to our numbers.
    Int16 decodedValue1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0);
    Int16 decodedValue2 = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(decodedValue1); // prints 12345
    Console.WriteLine(decodedValue2); // prints 31210
}
```